# csv file not determine according requirement

Tags: php, csv

I have create csv file like this

```
A    B    C
```

Every letter in different different column  where I read this file through php code it display in single array

like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => A    B   C
)
```

But i want this

```
 Array
    (
        [0] =>array(0=>A,1=>B,2=>C)
    )
```

is it posible

Comment: So you have a _Comma-Separated Values_ without comma ?

Comment: no i don't want comma separated value

Comment: The values are separated by tabs or spaces? You can jut use `explode` on your result

Comment: I guess you need to use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). Put the delimiter as `\t` which is used for tabulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your values are separated by tabs you could do it this way:

```
$values = array();
$content = file("data.csv");
foreach($content as $line) {
    $values[] = explode("\t", $line);
}
```